# My in-atmosphere traversible wormhole, does it make sense, and what propulsion is needed to gain access to it?

Tags: steampunk, wormholes, alien-geometry

I am trying to make up my own special Wormhole concept, researching and trying to understand what the practical and theoretical sciences we have, and am curious if its good or bad? The simple idea is that multiple planets in the solar system are connected together via in-atmospheric wormholes that can drift between the heights of Mount Everest, or the farthest into the thermosphere of a planetary body.

Edit: The planets in their Ancient and Medieval epochs had access to aircraft and spaceships that were at least of 21st century technology, whether it was starship-esque transport ships or aircraft-like VTOL's that traversed the wormholes with minimal input.

Throughout history they've been traversed by those of medieval technology, to those armed with musketry, the explanation obviously withholding in some circumstances. But now in the present, the people on Galoupia possess bolt-action rifles and early vacuum tubes, whereas those on Castoraina are further back yet understand the White Channels as well. Would coal-powered, airtight vessels make the trip between the bodies?

> The basic outline is that the solar system has an unexplained spatial
> phenomenon that has been lingering inconsistently between the planets,
> for several recorded millenniums. This gravitational phenomena is a
> massive and visually perceivable cone mass, like an outer-space
> wormhole that is in constant motion and in almost near transparency.
> These super-cones always possess the fundamental force of
> gravitational physics, but the inability to strongly channel
> electromagnetic forces further than any planets Thermosphere. These
> phenomena have been named many things by civilizations, but here
> they’re known as White Channels. What makes them unique is that
> they’re capable of filtering out dark matter and vacuum within its
> nature, and concentrating exotic matter in its place alongside
> residual planetary elements, the outside elements concentrated in a
> nebulous layer blanketing its exterior. Yet the most special feature
> of White Channels is that at both ends they’re the strongest
> gravitationally and the weakest along their length, enabling them to
> encapsulate the inside of their mouths, rudimentary elements of their
> host’s atmosphere, and pull up whatever comes close to them into the
> tunnel. White Channels are semi-permanent constructs that are in some
> strength of form always present in connecting bodies of gravity
> together, but their fabric can occasionally tear and occasionally
> mend, meaning they can create dramatic rifts or eventually meld into
> other White Channels - light years away. These events can allow
> electromagnetic energy to seep in, and in some instances change the
> direction of gravitational forces, transitioning WC’s from two-way
> highways to one-way roads or back. These masses ebb and flow, always
> in slow transient like a skyscraper under the duress of heavy winds,
> much to the chagrin of human history. When humanity was in the throes
> of the Bronze Age, White Channels were weaving through troposphere’s;
> Galoupia’s mountain ranges and Castoraina’s seas, allowing early
> civilizations to travel through them into White Streams, much smaller,
> temporary tunnels stretching along the locale, or the White Channels
> onto other bodies. Several thousand years later, they’ve gradually
> weakened. The dozen-or-so White Channels that sprung from Castoraina
> to Galoupia mostly evaporated, leaving several left withdrawn to the
> upper layers of their atmospheres. Long ago, galleys and armies in the
> right place, at the right time, could float away onto the next
> landscape yielding life or death in their journeys. Now, at game start
> when it requires rockets to grasp at them and the miraculous recovery
> of anti-gravity technology to exploit them fully, a new White Channel
> has exploded into the system. Named “White Heaven” by the locals on
> Castoraina for where it leads too, floats durably still in their
> Stratosphere above the western edge of Montessori.

Comment: I dont understand the question.   You state "Throughout history they've been traversed by those of medieval technology".  Then you ask if coal bathyscaphes could make the trip.  If a dude in a codpiece can make the trip on donkeyback I would think pretty much anything else would be ok.   Is there something about the airtight vessels that makes you think they would hang up in the wormhole?

Comment: I should've explained better, the lore reason being that they used advanced spaceships of 21st century design at the least, that eventually broke down before people could repair them, but managed to board them that self-navigated their trips through the wormholes.

Comment: This is your story. If you want a man riding a hummingbird to be able to do it, then he can. This is purely opinion.

Comment: I feel like the golden rule of worldbuilding is not to worry so much about the scientific explanations and just to set up your stories rules and stick to them especially when it comes to crazy science like wormholes. 

Biggest thing to worry about is that in order for air to not rush out like it would through a hole in a space ship the air pressure would to be the about the same still would probably have some crazy wether there though.

Answer (score 1):

Apologies if this isn’t answering your question.  I’m a little confused at exactly what your asking.

The big thing to keep in mind here is that wormholes between two planets with an atmosphere is going to end up being a lot like poking a hole through a space ship's hull. Air pressures would want to even out, and even in the upper atmosphere, the air pressure is significantly lower on the target planet.  Air would immediately begin to rush out the hole, likely with kinetic energy in similar quantities to the worlds' entire nuclear arsenals.

This is all to say, opening a wormhole between say the earth and the moon would be a world ending event. The entire planet's atmosphere would rush to this wormhole faster than weather has ever permitted, and would likely flatten the entire planet just with the wind speeds. This would keep happening until some sort of equilibrium is reached and the air pressure on the moon equals out with earths (likely at a significantly lower level probably resulting in the oceans evaporating).  The sun would keep stripping off the moon's new atmosphere until both bodies are left vacuums.

So you need to make sure the psi is the same on both bodies. Even then, unless weather is identical, the temperature differences between the two areas would probably result in some crazy weather, meaning that the area surrounding the wormhole would likely be extremely windy and the actual tunnel would be difficult but not impossible to navigate.

Wormholes are in a weird category as far as science goes. They might be possible but we don’t have any evidence they exist much less how exactly they’d work if they did. So I honestly wouldn’t try to focus on the physics of it — just treat it as a hole between the two systems they connect. If the physics cause any weird effects, we don’t know enough about it to predict it.